# How to enforce that a collection of objects are instances of the same child class

Tags: java, inheritance, class-hierarchy

Let's say we have the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    // body of parent
}

public class ChildA {
    // body of child A
}

public class ChildB {
    // body of child B
}
```

And we have a collection of objects of type `Parent` and a way to feed that collection:

```
List<Parent> list;

public void add(Parent newParent) {
    list.add(newParents);
}
```

When we start adding elements to that list, how can we ensure that they are only instances of the same class? Either instances of `ChildA` or instances of `ChildB`, but not both.

Comment: Why not have 2 lists: a `List<ChildA> childsA;` and a `List<ChildB> childsB;`? Or more to the point: why do you care which concrete instance it is?

Comment: Because that is not how my system works ;) I need to have a list of parents, but once instantiated objects are added only those of the same subclass are allowed.

Comment: Not a very solid design for your system. Typing a collection dynamically doesn't really work. Sure you can create hacks such as replacing the collection with a `Collections.checkedCollection` after you put the first element in, but it's not good design.

Comment: use `instanceof` to check type

Comment: @Rustam I can't because I don't know what subclass is being instantiated. It's the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
public void add(Parent newParent, Class<? extends Parent> clazz) {
    if(clazz.equals(list.get(0).getClass()) {
        list.add(newParents);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am asking. But cold it be possible to get rid of that second argument? I really want to keep the `add` method transparent. But it seems like this would be the only way, right?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for doesn't make sense.

If your list should only contain objects of a certain class; then use the generics to say so.

There is no point in telling the compiler "here is a list of fruit"; to then ask: "and how do I turn that list into one that only takes apples, but not bananas"?! The point is to declare it to be a "list of apples" initially; then the compiler can do all the checking for you.

Comment: Because it's not apple or bananas. It's just apples: only that either green apples or red apples.

Comment: Well, then consider to introduce some sort of marker interface for example. You know, if you want to use the compiler to do the work for you ... you have to give something to the compiler to be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As the type of the list would depend on the first element added to it, there is no way to have a compile time check. The only thing you could do would be an ugly runtime check:

```
class Foo {
    List<Parent> list;
    Class<? extends Parent> clazz = null;

    public void add(Parent newParent) {
        if (clazz == null) {
            clazz = newParent.getClass();
        } 
        if (! clazz.isInstance(newParent)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong type");
        }  
        list.add(newParent);
    }
}
```

However, I don't think you should use such an abomination. You should rethink your design instead.

Comment: This could work. However I am more interested in your last suggestion. Could you help me redesign it then? This is the actual hierarchy: https://gist.github.com/kpagcha/46b63a339d32131c0f1570dbe4d442a0 And we would have a `List<Timeslot>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just extend ArrayList for example like this:

```
public class WhackyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (this.size() > 0) {
            Object firstElement = this.get(0);
            if (e.getClass().equals(firstElement.getClass())) {
                return super.add(e);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return super.add(e);
    }
}
```

Then just use the regular add function to fill it up